# Not able to detect keypress in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk 10 with confbridge and have set a menu option in confbridge for key press 1. I am using voipvoip sip trunking services to call to phone numbers.
The problem is sometimes when the user presses 1 or any key then it's not detected(The menu option defined for that dtmf is not performed). This is particularly happening on Indian phone numbers.
Please this is only sometimes not everytime.

Please help me, is this any configuration issue or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug that was just resolved in the 10 branch for DTMF in India (or any DTMF with a very short duration).  I'm surprised that would occur over a SIP trunk, unless the DTMF was inband and not sent via an INFO request or RFC 2833.

You may want to apply the patch on the issue here to see if it resolves it for you.  It was written for Asterisk 1.8, but you should be able to get it to apply:

[ASTERISK-19610](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-19610)

Alternatively, you can get a diff of the commit that fixed this issue directly from the Asterisk 10 branch:

```
svn diff -c 372240 http://svn.asterisk.org/svn/asterisk/branches/10
```

Comment: Thank you Matt for your response. I applied the patch, it has minimized the problem but not completely resolved. Still the dtmf is not detected for indian numbers...earlier 50% cases were not detected but after applying the patch it has improved to 80%.

Comment: Is there any other complete solution? becoz this patch did not solve it completely. Please note I am facing problem only on Indian numbers. I would really appreciate for your help/suggestions.